# Angular 4 | How to access the span element and assign number on it?

Tags: angular

How can i access the span element and assign number on it?

```
<div class="container">
   <span>one</span>
   <span>two</span>
   <span>tree</span>
   <span>four</span>
   <span>five</span>
</div>
```

**then the result should be like this**

```
one | 1
two | 2
three| 3
four | 4
five | 5
```

i found out something @ViewChildren and local reference but when i access the span element i only get the length of it. how can i access the span and assign number on it?

Comment: What do you mean by "*assign number on it*"? Are you asking how to replace the contents?

Comment: nope not necessarily, sorry for my bad title it should be put number on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you can do it e.g. this way:

Template:

```
<div #container class="container">
   <span>one</span>
   <span>two</span>
   <span>tree</span>
   <span>four</span>
   <span>five</span>
</div>
```

Component:

```
@Component({/*...*/})
export class SomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('container') public container: ElementRef;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    // container will be undefined before this hook
    let spans = this.container.nativeElement.children;
    for (let i in spans) {
      spans[i].innerText += i + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

However I think you could just use standard Angular iterator:

```
interface Item {
  text: string;
  maybeMoreProperties?: number;
}

@Component({
  template: `<div class="container">
<span *ngFor="let item of items, let i = index">{{item.text}} {{i + 1}}</span>
</div>`
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public items: Array<Item> = [];

  constructor(someService: SomeService) {
    // let's say SomeService.getItems() returns array of {text: 'something'}
    this.items = someService.getItems();
}
```